# Read apps that user does not allow to show notifications? (Android)

Tags: android, settings, android-notifications

I'm researching how Android smartphone users manage notifications.

How can I build an app that automatically reads a list of the installed apps that the user does NOT allow to show notifications?
In Lollipop, that means the user has unchecked "Show notifications" under Settings > Apps > [app name]. In Marshmallow, that means the user has toggled on "Block all" for that app.

Additionally, for Marshmallow users, I'd like to know if the user has toggled on "Allow peeking."

Finally, would the user have to grant any permissions to my app in order to read these settings?